# How to make blinking screen flash _ swift 3

Tags: swift

I am trying get this code to produce multiple "flashes" to notify the user at the end of a countdown. Right now its working great for a single flash but I ideally would like three. Ive tried duplicating the code and putting the function in a loop to no avail.

Thanks in advance for the help!

//
Flash Function

```
func flash() {
    if let wnd = self.view{

        var v = UIView(frame: wnd.bounds)
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        v.alpha = 1

        wnd.addSubview(v)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.618, animations: {
            v.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: {(finished:Bool) in
            print("inside")
            v.removeFromSuperview()
        })
    }
}
```

//
Use of flash function

```
if (heatUpSeconds == 0) {
        heatUpTimer.invalidate()
        // testing screen flashing ideas here cameraView.frame

        flash()
```

Comment: Just call your flash function again from your completion block. Use a counter to keep track of how many times you've flashed already.

Answer (score -1):

```
var timer:Timer!

timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: delayBetweenFlashes, target: self, selector: #selector(self.flash), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: Please add short explanation to your answer.

Comment: I am not sure how you initialized your timer, did you make sure "repeats" is true? some developers by mistake initialize timer objects in a wrong way that it never fires, or fires but never repeats. have you got it repeating using my code?